# Python - How to add dictionary key using value from a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how you can use a value within a variable to make a new key for dictionary in Python 3.x

for example

```
person = {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
new_dictionary = {}
for k, v in person.items():
   new_dictionary.k = v
```

I get the following for new_dictionary

```
{'k': 'Doe'}
```

How do I get this output for new_dictionary?

```
{'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
```

**SOLUTION** (from below):

```
new_dictionary[k] = v
```

---

Comment: Are you sure your code even ran without any error?

Comment: You tried `new_dictionary[k] = v` and got en error for `new_dictionary.[k] = v`?

Comment: [Really?](http://ideone.com/9PrJSR)

Comment: No. @LisaL. 
`new_dictionary.k = v`  does not run without error in Python 3.x.

Comment: use  `new_dictionary[k] = v`.

Comment: Not sure why this question received 2 upvotes.

Comment: @Lisa it is not `new_dictionary.[k]`. Try `new_dictionary[k]` without `.`

Comment: Sorry.  new_dictionary[k] is correct.

Comment: Take time to post your question. Don't post random code and random outputs. Check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Using the attribute notation `new_dictionary.k` you will only ever set the literal value of `'k'`. Instead use the indexing notation:

```
person = {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
new_dictionary = {}
for k, v in person.items():
   new_dictionary[k] = v
```

Bonus: This also works in other languages, such as JavaScript.

Comment: `new_dictionary.k` wouldn't even work.

Comment: True. But you can use attribute notation on some kinds of Python objects (including some dictionary subclasses), though certainly not on the standard `dict`. My point is, that even in those cases, the best case you're ever going to get, under the most permissive assumptions, is to set the value of the literal `'k'` key.

Comment: BTW `new_dictionary[k] = v` is raising `TypeError: object does not support item assignment` for OP. So it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Then you are doing something *profoundly* wrong. This code, which I tested, runs fine under Python 2 or Python 3.

Comment: I am not, OP was. That's why I chose to close-vote it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary My mistake. Then OP is doing something profoundly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Eunice's answer does work:

```
for k, v in person.items():
    new_dictionary[k] = v
```

However, you forgot to remove the dot in your code:

```
new_dictionary.[k] = v
```

Should be:

```
new_dictionary[k] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are learning python, so you need different approach to copy and dictionary to other dict.

Here are few Approach for this:-

```
#First step create a dictionary
a = {"first_name":"Jon", "last_name":"Doe"}

#Approach 1: Using List comprehension
b = {key:value for key, value in a.items()}

#Approach 2: Initialise new dictionary and loop first to create new 
c = {}
for key, value in a.items():
    c[key] = value 

#Approach 3:Using Deep copy function
import copy    
d = copy.deepcopy(a)

#Approach 4:Using Update function of dictionary
e = {}    
e.update(a)

#Finally Print all dicts
print (a, b, c, d, e)

#Below is Output of a,b,c,d,e:-

({'first_name': 'Jon', 'last_name': 'Doe'}, {'first_name': 'Jon', 'last_name': 'Doe'}, {'first_name': 'Jon', 'last_name': 'Doe'}, {'first_name': 'Jon', 'last_name': 'Doe'}, {'first_name': 'Jon', 'last_name': 'Doe'})
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying `

```
 person = {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
 new_dictionary = {}
 for k in person.keys():
     new_dictionary[k] = person[k]

 print(new_dictionary)`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dictionary = {**person}
```

This will create `new_dictionary` using the key-value pairs from the `person` dictionary.

After that, you can update it as follows:

```
new_dictionary = {**new_dictionary, **person_2}
```

This only works in Python 3.5+ (proposed in PEP 448), thanks Mark Tolonen!

Comment: `new_dictionary.update(person)` would be less esoteric and would work in a wider range of Pythons.

Comment: @MarkTolonen It's a good idea to learn the expressive features of Python. Furthermore, the question is tagged Python 3.x

Comment: That only works in 3.5+. BTW, not the downvoter...just a comment.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Why not just do `new_dictionary = person.copy()`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary To keep the usage of unpacking operator consistent

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way :

```
person = {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
new_dictionary = {}
for k, v in person.items():
   new_dictionary.setdefault(k, v)

print(new_dictionary)
```

Output :

```
{'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
```

Comment: `new_dictionary = person.copy()`?

Comment: yep @AshwiniChaudhary.


`>>> person = {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
>>> new_dictionary = {}
>>> new_dictionary = person.copy()
>>> new_dictionary
{'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
`